# OPTIONS http://localhost:8545/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'm getting this error in Console `OPTIONS http://localhost:8545/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` ,`Error: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""`  when trying to execute this piece of code from a webpage on VPS (http://example.com/test-app/web3-test.html):

```
   <html>
    ......
    <body>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createAccount();">Create Account</button>
    .....

    <script src="/js/web3.js-1.0.0-beta.34/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

    function createAccount(){
        web3.eth.personal.newAccount('123456789abc', function(err, res){
            console.log("Error: "+err);
            console.log("Res: "+res);
        });
    }

    </script>
</body>
<html>
```

I have installed already ethereum on my VPS.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ethereum
```

And `geth --rpc` is displaying this in terminal(connected with live server through ssh)

```
INFO [04-17|20:14:09] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/root/.ethereum/geth.ipc
INFO [04-17|20:14:09] HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://127.0.0.1:8545    cors= vhosts=localhost
```

I guess its a CORS issue, is there geth default setting to fix?(I don't want to install CORS extension for temp fix also I'm not using Node js, its a simple web page where I included web3 version 1 file)

Also tried this: `geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal`

And output in terminal is:

```
INFO [04-17|20:52:32] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/root/.ethereum/geth.ipc
INFO [04-17|20:52:32] HTTP endpoint opened                     url=http://127.0.0.1:8545    cors=* vhosts=localhost
```

Thank you everyone...

Comment: that gonna work if you open your browser inside the VPS. If you navigate to your VPS page through your PC `localhost` is you not the VPS. So you might need to change `localhost` with the VPS public address

Comment: Thank you how could I change localhost with the VPS public address?

Comment: just change this line: `var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))` but the VPS should also listen for incoming connections.

Comment: @mirg how I can prevent other user to not use my 64.421.252.5:8545 address in their pages? only my page can access this port on my server?

Comment: then you have to create a backend that interact with your node instead of using it in the client side.